# I want to use a unix socket instead of TCP to connect to my PHP-FPM proxy, I'm using Centos7

Tags: php, apache, sockets, centos7

I'm attempting to use a unix socket instead of TCP to connect to my proxy PHP-FPM on Centos7 with Apache2 ... anyone got a solution?

I tried to use SetHandler but I think I got it wrong...

the below didn't work for me...

SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/var/run/php72-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"

Comment: TCP is a protocol used by sockets, im not sure what your really asking

Comment: I also tried: replacing listen = 127.0.0.1:9056 with listen = /var/run/php56-fpm.sock

Comment: tim - I want to use a unix socket instead of TCP connection to my php-fpm

Comment: IE: https://community.centminmod.com/threads/switch-from-tcp-to-unix-domain-sockets.307/

Comment: Found a site that claimed it only works on Apache 2.4.9 and greater.. I'm currently using 2.4.6, so I guess I'll give up until I can update my apache.